# bash .sh script looping instead of ending/exiting

Tags: bash, script, bash-scripting, sh, infinite-loop

I'm writing my very first bash script.  Everytime I've run it to make sure it works, everything works exactly as I'd like it to with the exception of the `done` command at the very end.  Instead it loops around to the question asking the user if they're sure they want to authorize it to make the changes it will make.

Since this is my first time writing a script, I'm positive there are better, more efficient ways ot performing the action I've written it to do, so I'm not asking for input in that regard.  The fact that it does what I'd like it to do (even though it can't seem to end), is good enough for me at this point.

Here's the script (anything you see `[with backets]` is something I've included just for this SU:Question, and not actually in the script itself):

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -e 'print "\n"x128;'

echo ' ' ; echo ' ' ; 

echo    "


[Omitted to make this SU:Question shorter]

    ⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓

    TLDR the above info?
    That's okay, it is also available in the included README.

            ⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓
    "

[This does not do anything, just something neat I learned how to do...]

    c=3 # seconds to wait
    REWRITE="\e[25D\e[1A\e[K"
    echo "    First thing first... I'll need you have run this as ROOT/SU..."
    while [ $c -gt 0 ]; do 
        c=$((c-1))
        sleep 1
        #echo -e "  ${REWRITE}$c"
    done

    echo ' '



 if [ $(id -u) != 0 ]; then
     echo "    Oops, you didn't run this as ROOT or SU! Here is the proper command:

    ⟹   sudo ./enable-wifi.sh   ⟸

            "
    exit
     # elevate script privileges

     else
        echo "    ⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓

    Awesome, you're ready!"


 fi

while true; do
    read -p "
    Just to make sure...  Do you wish to execute this script?

    Please enter [Y/y] / [N/n] here:  " yn 
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi ; sudo rfkill unblock all ; echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/acer-wmi.conf ; clear ; echo ' ' ; echo ' ' ; echo 'DONE!' ; echo ' ' ; echo ' ' ; echo 'The WIFI Card should be working now!' ; echo ' ' ; echo ' ';;
        [Nn]* ) echo ' ' ; echo '    ⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓⁓

    You have decided to cancel, this script will end immediately 
    without making any changes to your HP Envy x360.!

    '  ; exit;;
#        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac


done
```

Thanks very much for taking a look at this question and helping me out!

~ Ev

Comment: Well, what did you expect it to do? `while true; do` means “do this forever”; there’s no way for the loop to terminate except by the `exit` that happens if the user enters “No.”

Answer (score 1):

> with the exception of the `done` command

**`done` is not a command.**

It seems there is a misunderstanding: the keyword `done` does not mean that the script is done and can end execution. It is instead the counterpart of the previous `do` keyword in the [`while...do`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html). It means: when the `while` condition is false, execute the next instruction after the `done` keyword.

Maybe you want to add an `exit` at the end of the list of commands that get executed if the user chooses `Y`.

**Update:**

I mentioned `exit` simply because it was already used in the `[Nn]` branch, but that would only have *fixed* the script. Using `break` instead of `exit` as suggested by [Gordon Davisson](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson) is instead a better idea that represents an *improvement*, allowing for further development of the script.

Comment: Using `break`  (instead of `exit`) would also work -- that'd make it continue after the end of the loop (the `done` keyword), so if there were any more to the script that'd get executed.